# How to make player animation in sfml?

Tags: c++, sfml

i wanted to make player a bit realistic instead of just hovering around like a ghost. this is my code just some basic gravity and movement, i want to make jumping animation, walking animation, turn left and turn right animation. how do i do that?

here code:

```
void Game::initTexture()
{
    if (!texture.loadFromFile("/home/webmaster/Documents/vscode-sfml/src/Ball_and_Chain_Bot/pixil-frame-0(1).png"))
    {
        std::cout << "failed to load texture\n";
        rect.setTexture(texture);
        rect.setPosition(this->window->getView().getCenter());
        rect.setScale(2,2);
    }
}
```

rendering:

```
void Game::render()
{
    this->window->clear(sf::Color(239, 235, 216));
    this->window->draw(rect);
    this->window->display();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to show your actual code, the headers are not very useful. Regardless:

1. Define some animations. Each animation should have a target length and a number of frames that cover that target. At the beginning it is easiest to make every frame be equally long, but nobody stops you from having frame 1 take 0.2s, frame 2 0.8s, and frame 3 0.15s.
2. add code to keep track of a "current animation" that properly cycles through the frames on the proper timescale (ie show each frame for 0.25s if you have 4 frames and a target of 1s). Some animations may cycle, such as the "running" or "idle" animation. A common technique for storing animations is a "texture atlas" that contains all frames of an animation. You can then use `sf::Shape::setTextureRect` to select a part of the texture to draw.
3. update your movement and input code to change the animation if the state of the character changes

Let us define the frames of an animation in terms of `sf::IntRect` sections of a given sprite sheet: ([example sprite sheet](http://www.thealmightyguru.com/Wiki/images/1/1a/Super_Metroid_-_SNES_-_Sprite_Sheet_-_Samus.png))

```
std::vector<sf::IntRect> idle {
  {0, 0, 35, 61}
};
std::vector<sf::IntRect> runningRight {
  {657, 473, 43, 52}, // first frame is at 657x473 and is 43x52 pixels
  // other frames.
};
```

We can define an `Animation` class with the following data and methods:

```
class Animation {
  public:
  Animation(const std::vector<sf::IntRect>& frames, float duration, bool cycles = true) : frames(frames), frameTime(duration / frames.size()), cycles(cycles) { reset(); }

  void reset() {
    currentFrame = 0;
    currentFrameTime = 0;
  }
  void update(float dt);
  const sf::IntRect& getCurrentRect() const { return frames[currentFrame]; }

  private:
  const std::vector<sf::IntRect>& frames;
  const float frameTime;
  bool cycles;
  int currentFrame;
  float currentFrameTime;
};
```

This implements most of step 2: keeping track of which frame should be on screen, assuming `update(dt)` is called every frame.

Now all that remains is the `update` method:

```
void Animation::update(float dt) {
  currentFrameTime += dt;
  // TODO: take `cycles` into account.
  while (currentFrameTime >= frameTime) {
    currentFrameTime -= frameTime;
    currentFrame = (currentFrame + 1) % frames.size();
  }
}
```

Finally, to hook this up, create the following variables:

```
sf::Texture textureAtlas = ...;
Animation currentAnimation{idle, 10.0f};
sf::Sprite player(textureAtlas, currentAnimation.getCurrentRect());
```

- In your game's `update()` code, call `currentAnimation.update(dt)`.
- In the render function, make sure to call `player.setTextureRect(currentAnimation.getCurrentRect())`.
- If you receive input, do something like `currentAnimation = Animation{runningRight, 1.0f}`;

Comment: do i need to make a sprite before making animation?

Comment: Yes, a `sf::Sprite` is a common way for showing a moving thing in SFML.

Comment: See edit for a mostly complete Animation class and information on how to hook it up. Some work is still required from your part though.

Comment: one more question what do you mean by "take `cycles` into account."

Comment: Some animations might not cycle. For example, a jumping animation might keep playing the last frame until the player lands, a shooting animation will shoot once, etc. And then there are compound animations: shooting wile running should return to the running animation once the shooting animation ends.

Comment: It is up to you to define the behavior of the `update` function for animations where `cycles` is `false`. Or just ignore it if you want all animations to cycle.

Comment: i need to change sprite to textureAtlas?

Comment: That is one approach, yes. If you want to have a lot of single-frame `sf::Texture` objects and switch between them that works too.

Comment: because the running animation and idle seperate do i need to load them 1 by 1

Comment: That would be the most logical approach, yes. Please stop asking me for permission and just *try* stuff. As I said, you are free to post new questions if you get stuck somewhere concrete.